What are all the ways of changing the status bar?
When I navigate to a certain page that doesn't show the status bar and then back to the previous page that had a status bar is now gone. What is causing this? I have little memory of working on this and can't find relevant code. So I'm wondering all the ways I can control the status bar. Thanks!

Use SafeArea.

To update the status bar properties, you can check the systemOverlayStyle property of the AppBar. Alternatively, if you don't have an AppBar, you can use AnnotatedRegion to update the status bar properties.
Using AppBar:
If you are using an AppBar, you can directly set the systemOverlayStyle property:
AppBar(
  systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    // Set your properties here
  ),
  // Other properties
)

Without AppBar:
If you don't have an AppBar, you can use AnnotatedRegion to update the status bar properties:
AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
  value: const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    // Set your properties here
  ),
  child: // Your child widget
)

